# Selling mutual fund and buying equivalent ETF: Can I 1031 exchange?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I have a taxable investment account consisting of Vanguard mutual funds that I have held for less than a year.

I recently learned that ETFs are more tax efficient in nature because the managers don't have to rebalance like mutual fund.

Many of these mutual funds have an ETF version, so I am thinking of converting. Can I do a 1031 exchange so that selling the mutual funds doesn't generate a tax liability?

Comment: Assuming this is United States? If so can you edit and add country tag. Tax regulations depend on country

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do that.

[From the IRS:](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Like-Kind-Exchanges-Under-IRC-Code-Section-1031)

> Finally, certain types of property are specifically excluded from Section 1031 treatment. Section 1031 does not apply to exchanges of:
>
> - Inventory or stock in trade
> - **Stocks, bonds, or notes**
> - **Other securities or debt**
> - Partnership interests
> - Certificates of trust

I **highlighted** the relevant items for emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do a 1031 exchange with stocks, bonds, mutual funds, or ETFs.

There really isn't much difference between an ETF and its equivalent index mutual fund. Both will have minimal capital gains distributions. I would not recommend selling an index mutual fund and taking a short-term capital gain just to buy the equivalent ETF.